# Run time broker takes more time to remove from task mahager

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps

I have created the UWP application. When I closed the application the process takes more time to remove from the task manager (almost 30 seconds). When I expanded the process in the task manager it has only run time broker running. Is there any way to reduce the time of closing the run time broker?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to reduce the time of closing the run time broker?

The `Runtime Broker` application is a Microsoft program included with Windows 8 (and newer versions) that handles permissions for all local Universal Windows Platform (UWP) applications.

The purpose of `Runtime Broker` is to monitor and manage all permissions granted to running UWP applications. If you’ve ever opened the Windows Store, or launched any UWP application from a built-in start menu “tile” or open `FileOpenPicker` chances are this application has used the `Runtime Broker` to verify its proper `permissions` and `Capabilities`.

Currently, we could not stop `Runtime Broker` manually, and it is system level. It will managed by the operation system.

> When I closed the application the process takes more time to remove from the task manager (almost 30 seconds).

The runtime will be closed 30s later than the main process. And this feature can ensure that app is restarted within 30 seconds after closed, the Runtime broker will not recreate to save CPU usage. The `Runtime Broker` application is typically idling with no CPU usage and low memory usage.

Comment: Is there any microsoft link??

Comment: Currently, there is no relative official document about `Runtime Broker`. But there are some [blog](https://airbrake.io/blog/what-is/runtime-broker) introduce it.